# "Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:"

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, r-caret

I took the following code out of a textbook, "[Machine Learning With R](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/machine-learning-r)" by Brett Lantz, however copied exactly the same to the console from the textbook,

```
> library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
> library(kernlab)

Attaching package: ‘kernlab’

The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

alpha

> set.seed(300)
> ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
> bagctrl <- bagControl(fit = svmBag$fit, predict = svmBag$pred, aggregate = svmBag$aggregate)
> setwd("~/2148OS_code/chapter 11")
> credit <- read.csv("credit.csv")
> svmbag <- train(default ~ ., data = credit, "bag", trControl = ctrl, bagControl = bagctrl)
```

I get this response. Whats wrong?

```
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1    
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

The warnings are

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, i) :
  some row.names duplicated: 3,6,10,13,17,19,23,24,26,27,30,32,34,36,38,41,42,45,49,54,59,60,61,64,66,69,71,72,77,80,81,90,95,102,103,106,112,114,117,118,122,125,127,132,133,137,139,141,143,146,148,151,152,155,158,161,174,176,178,181,185,187,188,189,191,194,203,208,210,212,215,216,218,219,221,223,225,229,230,235,236,239,245,246,262,266,269,271,272,276,279,282,283,285,286,287,288,296,299,305,308,309,313,314,315,317,318,319,322,323,327,328,330,332,333,335,336,338,339,343,347,349,350,352,354,358,360,361,363,366,367,368,369,371,377,379,387,389,392,394,396,397,399,400,410,412,413,414,421,425,428,437,438,441,443,445,446,448,451,453,461,467,469,471,479,481,482,484,486,487,489,491,493,503,504,506,508,511,512,514,517,519,521,522,524,529,530,532,534,537,538,545,547,550,552,555,562,570,579,582,584,588,589,590,601,606,608,610,611,614,615,618,619,623,627,628,629,630,632,634,636,638,641,642,645,653,656,659,660,661,663,667,669,672,673,676,679,681,686,687,690,693,700,701,702,707,708,721,722,724,725,728, [... truncated]
2: In data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, i) :
  some row.names duplicated: 3,5,8,9,13,15,18,21,25,27,29,33,36,37,41,44,45,51,52,53,55,59,60,64,66,67,72,76,77,80,91,92,96,97,102,103,104,107,110,111,113,116,119,121,122,123,127,130,133,136,139,140,143,145,147,148,149,154,158,160,164,166,168,169,171,174,176,177,178,180,182,185,187,195,199,203,205,216,218,220,223,226,231,234,236,237,238,242,245,2
```

Comment: I've just stepped through the code provided in the private area of the Packt site.  I can reproduce the issue, so either `caret` has changed and the code is out of date, or there is a problem with the provided code.  The error message isn't helpful, so it isn't clear what the problem is.

Comment: its a section on bootstrap ensembles. Im using a data set of credit features to predict loan defaults and this is supposed to be one of the better methods of getting a high accuracy and high kappa statistic using svms. is there any other way i can do this?

Comment: You could submitting an erratum on the Packt site, or try contacting the author https://leadersandbest.umich.edu/contact/directory-oud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the code provided by packed for the second edition.

If you setup parallel processing the warnings will disappear. You will still end up with the error of the missing accuracy metrics.

This error is caused by the fact that there were missing values in resampled performance measures. That might happen if there is a resample where one of the outcome classes (in this case default) has zero samples so sensitivity or specificity is undefined.

I also ran a test with the GermanCredit data included in the caret package and this generates the same error.

Comment: `If you setup parallel processing the warnings will disappear.` That might only be the case because of how some programs (RStudio) handle standard out. It might not be due to the problem going away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before.  Problem was in  class variable values.

Please try to change class values  from "0","1" to e.g. "A" , "B" and try the same code.